# How to get all short date formats for a locale in angular 5

Tags: angular

I need to implement a feature where user can select a locale and all available date/time options should be shown for that locale e.g. in windows control panel -> Region and language dialog has various formats and if I select a particular locale format then can see various short date formats available. 
 
 Need to implement something similar where user can select a format and choose date settings for the screen.

[image]

 
Have tried searching angular i18n module for APIs to read short date formats and long date formats for a locale but couldn't find any.

 
Also, looked around for getLocaleDateFormat in i18n APIs but that gives a single format instead of list of available formats.

Is it possible to get list of short date formats for a locale in angular 5?
Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried momentjs.com ? It's not angular but you can install typings for that and use it as just like a plain class.

Comment: @SevOlens - yes, have tried momentjs but couldn't find any API. Looked at longDateFormat but looks like you need to pass in L | LL | LLL to retrieve a format